# Merging Repositories

Tags: repository, localrepository

So that I can supply our offline servers (Ubuntu 16-18) with software, I run a virtual machine which mirrored http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ .

With the available packages I can always manage. Now web servers have fallen into my area of responsibility. The packages for PHP are here: https://packages.sury.org/php/

My question now is, can I clone the PHP repository into the same directory as the official Ubuntu packages?
Or do I have to create a new path?
If you could put both repositories into one directory, it would have the advantage that you would have to add less entries to the Sources.list.

Comment: Which index files are we talking about exactly? I just need the pool folder from the PHP repository. In which index file would the additional packages have to be added?
Theoretically it would be possible to have the merging of the index files run automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you could merge them, but then you'ld have to also merge the index files of the repositories - and every time the ubuntu upstream updated, you'ld have to merge the index files again.

There is software that claims to do it for you [here](https://www.aptly.info).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the linking, it would have programmed it itself, but it's much more comfortable :-)